# command button works on second click and accordion first tab content is empty

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I Have an accordion panel with a list of students and I have set dynamic="true", In a tabs of accordion panel, I have command button which invokes the method in backing bean. 
here the content of first tab is empty and rest all is fine. To correct this ,I have set dynamic="false" now the content of tab is appearing but command button click doesnot invoke the method of backing bean on first click. Iam not sure what is happening.. Im using prime faces 3.4 and jsf2

```
<p:accordionPanel  value="#{testBean.students}" var="stud"  dynamic="true"  activeIndex="#{systemManagedBean.formBean.id}">  

              <p:tab title="#{stud.name}" id="studId">  
             <p:commandButton process="@this"  value="edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil" styleClass="btn-primary" style="margin-left:734px;" action="#{testBean.edit}">

            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.stydent}" value="#{stud}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>

            </p:commandButton>
```

I have tried proceess=@form did not make any change..

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working:

The xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <p:accordionPanel value="#{so15320248.students}" var="student">
        <p:tab title="#{student.name}">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="Edit" actionListener="#{so15320248.edit(student)}"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

The managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "so15320248")
@ViewScoped
public class SO15320248 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2285963068688871710L;

    private List<Student> students;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(new Student("Student 1"));
        students.add(new Student("Student 2"));
    }

    public void edit(Student student) {
        System.out.println("===========================");
        System.out.println(student.getName());
        System.out.println("===========================");
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```